# Why can't I install tensorflow in fedora 39? Also can't change the python version globally

Tags: fedora, python3

I am unable to change the python version globally on my fedora 39.so.
 every time I try to install tensorflow,it shows either

> couldn't find a version that satisfies the requirement

or while installing keras,it shows

> error couldn't build wheel for dm-tree.

I have checked if the hardware is unsupported ,but it is.
Some days back I had installed linux mint and had installed tensorflow-cpu hassle-free on it.
But when I moved to fedora it's showing errors.

Comment: It would be helpful to know what commands you are running to change your Python version, which Python version you are attempting to change it to and what commands you are running to install packages.  Also, please post the full error messages that the commands produce so everyone has a better idea of what is going on.

Comment: I realised that the python version in fedora 39 ,python 3.12 ,isn't currently supported by tensorflow.